# Overlay orthophoto with DTM

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, software-recommendations, dxf, orthophoto

I am having a .dxf DSM and a georeferenced .tiff orthphoto. I would now like to simply overlay the orthophoto onto the terrain for visualization purposes. The DSM contains buildings, whose triangles should be colored differently. It works with texture overlays in AutoCAD 3D, however the performance is way too weak. Does anybody now an easier and quicker solution to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloud platform Melown.com, you upload DSM and .tiff and you can visualise it. See here an example here: https://www.melown.com/console/link/VEtUb18bSfjxmDNkFC37?mapLoadMode=fit

I am affilated with Melown Tech.